# Debugging Badboxes

Tags: pdftex, miktex, debugging, bad-box

I am currently working on a document where I get a lot of badboxes, unfortunately I don't get any information on where does badboxes occur (apart form the file). How can I find these badboxes effectively?

That is the output that Latex gives me:

```
Overfull \vbox (19.03992pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


Overfull \hbox (27.75592pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]|
 []


Overfull \vbox (19.03992pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


Overfull \hbox (27.75592pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]|
 []


Overfull \vbox (19.03992pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


Overfull \hbox (27.75592pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
[]|
 []
```

What is the proper method to debug that?

I am using MikTeX on Windows.

Edit:

This works without warnings:

```
\usepackage[
headtopline,plainheadtopline,
headsepline,plainheadsepline,
footsepline,plainfootsepline,
footbotline,plainfootbotline,
markcase=ignoreuppercase
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

This creates warnings:

```
\usepackage[
headtopline=:textwithmarginpar,plainheadtopline,
headsepline=:textwithmarginpar,plainheadsepline,
footsepline=:textwithmarginpar,plainfootsepline,
footbotline=:textwithmarginpar,plainfootbotline,
markcase=ignoreuppercase
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

BR Patrick

Comment: I these are bad boxes with the same values, it probably lies in the headers/footers. To be sure, remove them completely (using the empty page style, for instance) and check whether  these error messages disappear.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the problem. I have two lines in the header&footer, those lines are longer than the width of the text and thus creates an error. How can I do that without warnings? I will add the snippet of that code in the question above.

Comment: Instead of adding a snippet please add a minimal complete document which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the declarations

```
\showboxdepth=3 \showboxbreadth=30
```

and the warning messages will show (some of) the text in the overfull boxes, which should help diagnose the problem.

An overfull vbox "when \output is active" could mean the page could not be broken and ran into the bottom margin, or it could be something else on the page layout, like that \headheight is set too small. (Only \headheight: strangely there is no restriction based on \footheight.)  Try

```
\addtolength\headheight{28pt}
```

Overfull hbox also probably comes from the header setup. I am not particularly familiar with the koma-script specification format, but `headtopline=:textwithmarginpar,plainheadtopline,` looks suspicious. Hmm.... "However, the package’s interface is almost too flexible and consequently not easy for the average user to comprehend." So I'll give up there, except to say that I couldn't find "=:" in the koma documentation -- 565 pages of it!

OK, I didn't give up, but it looks like you specified the full width of the text (text plus marginpar plus separation) as the *offset* to the header line. That's ridiculous, and probably accounts for the overfull hbox; and then it broke into multiple lines, giving overfull vbox.